# Another CustomBadge Dilemma

Tags: iphone, ios

I didn't know how to update my previous post/question so I started another.  (I haven't asked a lot of question here. Still very new to stackoverflow)

I now have three badges and need to control them together (or independent) of each other.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[self fillBadges];

//********** Start Custom Badge All ***************//
NSString *myNewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",allBadge];

if (allBadge >= 1) {
    CustomBadge *customBadgeAll = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:myNewString];
    customBadgeAll.tag = 100;
    [customBadgeAll setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 90, customBadgeAll.frame.size.width, customBadgeAll.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:customBadgeAll];

}else{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:100] removeFromSuperview];
}

//********** Start Custom Badge 1  ***************//
NSString *myNewString1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",badge1];

if (badge1 >= 1) {
    CustomBadge *customBadge1 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:myNewString1];
    customBadge1.tag = 200;
    [customBadge1 setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 165, customBadge1.frame.size.width, customBadge1.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:customBadge1];
}else{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:200] removeFromSuperview];
}

//********** Start Custom Badge 2 ***************//
NSString *myNewString2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",badge2];
if (badge2 >= 1) {
    CustomBadge *customBadge2 = [CustomBadge customBadgeWithString:myNewString2];
    customBadge2.tag = 300;
    [customBadge2 setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 232, customBadge2.frame.size.width, customBadge2.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:customBadge2];
}else{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:300] removeFromSuperview];
}

//********** End Custom Badge ***************//

[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

}

The if else statements are working. However the removeFromSuperview (while it works) only removes the badges one by one in reverse order from the way they were set, and only if I leave the view and come back to it. In this case 3 times. For example: To turn on 3 badges. In viewBadgeSet, badge2 is set to >1, then badge1 set to >1 and finally badge3 set to >1 (In no particular order). I look at the view in viewMainButtons and three badges are now on. Now if all badges are set to 0 in viewBadgeReset then I come back to viewMainButtons, badge3 will be gone. I then must go to another view, then back to viewMainButtons, badge1 will be gone, leave the view again and come back to viewMainButtons and finally badge3 will be gone. I hope this makes sense. How can I remove all badges from the view together? Sorry for being so dense. I hope this question is no too vague. I'm just not sure what to do.

(Apparently I don't have enough points to enter into a chat)

Thanks

Comment: What is the activity or event that should remove the buttons? At the moment your code is within the viewWillAppear: method which is only run when the view appears on the screen. That explains why it only works when you leave and return to the view.

Comment: The removeFromSuperview works when allBadge < 1, or any of the other if statements are < 1. I think its the stacking order of the subview I need to deal with. I'm looking in to that now. Since I'm new to iOS I digging a bit.

Comment: I understand the code, but what's the thing that happens in your app, where allBadge can be less than 1? At the moment you only check the value of allBadge when the view appears, but it sounds like you need it to be checking while the view is on the screen. What causes the allBadge value to change?

Comment: I found my problem. It seems that when allBadges is >= 1 I add a subView. (looking at the subView array) I don't want to do that. So now I just remove the subView using the tag, before adding a new subView. Now all 8 of my badges are working. The badges increment with their new numbers and when allBadges (or any other badge) is <  1 the view is removed. Thanks to everyone for their direction and help.